# Workaround for `Combination of indirect name lookup and call not supported` error?

Tags: raku

Google turns up nothing on this error: `Combination of indirect name lookup and call not supported`

My code:

```
use Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses;
unit class Vimwiki::File::ContentStr;

has Str $.content;


method process($class) {
    $!content = Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses::($class).process($!content);
}
```

The compiler is not happy with this and complains with aforesaid error. If I hard-code in in the `$class` name, everything works.

Anyway around this?

Comment: "Google turns up nothing on this error: `Combination of indirect name lookup and call not supported`" Are you using quotes? I get 5 results for [a google for "Combination of indirect name lookup and call not supported"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Combination+of+indirect+name+lookup+and+call+not+supported%22).

Comment: The error message comes from [here](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/34d281642680574d9515411eb3187ac542272859/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L6366).

Comment: No sure. I could have meant "nothing immediately obvious that could help me."

Answer (score 1):

OK, solution is to precede the package name with `::`, like so:

`$!content = ::Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses::($class).process($!content);`

Documentation is here: https://docs.raku.org/language/packages#Looking_up_names

Though I don't know precisely why what I was doing originally behaves differently.